# jQuery UI - Why is there a dotted outline around an anchor that shouldn't be active?

Tags: jquery-ui

I'm using the dialog box modal from jQuery UI and when I open up the dialog box, the first or one of the first few anchors has a dotted line around it without me clicking on anything. Once I click anywhere on the screen it goes away. So it appears that the dialog box is activating the anchor, but how it's doing that is beyond me.

Comment: UPDATE: the dotted outline does represent focus—most browsers use a glowing ring. jQuery UI and other modals are following accessibility best practices by focusing the first focusable element. https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices-1.1/examples/dialog-modal/dialog.html

If you don't want the focus ring to be visible for non-keyboard users, you should do something like this:
`a:focus:not(:focus-visible) { outline: none }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this dotted line just represents focus.  It may be the case that jquery-ui is actually setting the focus on the first hyperlink, but (without pouring through jquery-ui source code) I think it's equally plausible that your browser is doing it on its own.

If it's the browser, I suspect it's because the dialog div is receiving the focus, and the browser's only way to deal with that is to place the focus on the first interactive thing in that div:  the anchor.

What happens if there are no anchors in the dialog div?  What happens if there's a text input before any anchors?

If this is something the browser's doing, do yourself a favor and stop worrying about it.  You could loose a lot of time and introduce a lot of browser-specific, hard to maintain code by trying to make it behave differently.

Comment: I went to the jQuery UI demo page (http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/) and it appears that Firefox 3.6 has this problem no matter what, so you're somewhat correct with your assumption that it's just the browser. And yes, if I don't have any anchors, then there's no dotted line around anything.

However, Webkit and IE don't have any dotted lines on jQuery UI's demo page, but do when I build a barebone test dialog. So not really sure what's causing this. I'm using it on a Drupal build, so maybe there's some conflict there. I'll probably try a test on my personal site & see if it happens there.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not specifically sure why this happens exactly, however if you want to change the behavior of this you can add to your css and the outline should disappear.

```
div.ui-dialog a { outline: none }
```

Comment: With new Jquery-UI 1.10.3, I had to set .ui-button { outline: none;}

Comment: or just the close button... .ui-dialog .ui-dialog-titlebar-close

Comment: The outline is for accessibility, so you should never remove it entirely. Now we have focus-visible if you want to remove the outline for non-keyboard users.
`a:focus:not(:focus-visible) { outline: none }`